# How to set text over bottom button background in tablelayout

Tags: android, button, text, tablelayout

Here's what i have:

Here's the layout:`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/process_search"
    android:text="@string/home_screen" 
    style="@style/SubPageHeader"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_round_edges"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_round_edges_white_back"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="1">
               <!-- android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"-->

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_home_dados_pessoais"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center|bottom"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_dados_pessoais_complete"
                        android:text="@string/home_dados_pessoais"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_home_historico_pesquisas"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_pesquisa_complete"
                        android:text="@string/home_historico_pesquisas"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"  />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_home_configuracoes"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_config_complete"
                        android:text="@string/home_configuracoes"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_home_opcoes"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="10dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_android_complete"
                        android:text="template"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

What i want is put the text in the button area but at the bottom. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new drawable that is that grey square "background" of your button, and set that to the android:background. Modify your button drawable to only be the icons, with a transparent background. Just doing this will get you what you want, a button with grey background, text on the bottom, image on the top.

*Edit: added example below*

**Icon Drawable** (R.drawable.btnIcon1)

[image: icon]

**Background Drawable** (R.drawable.btnBackground)

[image]

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_home_dados_pessoais"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/btnBackground"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btnIcon1"
    android:text="@string/home_dados_pessoais"
    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Comment: Not following, so you set android_background to transparent or the grey square?

Comment: see my edit. after you get your drawables created, you just need to set the `drawableTop` on each button to the appropriate icon, and `background` to the grey square background drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FrameLayout`. According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control
>   their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each
>   child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

In your case, the xml would become:

```
<TableRow>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_home_dados_pessoais"
        android:layout_width="0dip"                       
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_dados_pessoais_complete" />
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_dados_pessoais"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold">
      <!-- The rest of the row -->
</FrameLayout>
</TableRow>
```

---

On a side note, I suggest you use a style for your buttons: most of their styling is redundant. Check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for an example.